# Answering your own question multiple times?

Tags: discussion

It seems weird to me that the software allows you to write multiple answers to a question, let alone your own question.

Example:
[How do you efficiently empty beer bottles?](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/4927/how-do-you-efficiently-empty-beer-bottles)

Comment: I think I've committed a faux pas. I'd considered putting these options in the question, but I've seen people warned against "answering ones own question", so I tried the multiple answers for people to independently vote/comment on. Is there a better way to handle this? I'd be happy to delete my answers.

Comment: I don't think you need to go to the extreme of deleting your answers.  But in this particular example its a very subjective thing.  You might be able to scientifically experiment which way is faster, but its still largely a personal opinion on how one person choses to empty bottles.  In this case then, its better as a wiki.

Comment: That works for me. I had no idea this would be so controversial... I'll try to behave in the future :)

Comment: Actually, to be honest, it was just something I was thinking about (while waiting for the glug-glug-glug), and considering experimenting to get good data. Then I thought I could share that on the SE site. Then I noticed that the site's Area 51 profile shows that there aren't enough questions coming in, so I figured I'd just get it in there to help do my part.

Comment: Its all good Ray

Comment: I just saw a guy answer his own question, then declare his own answer the best answer, after just 24 hours.  This is just dumb.  https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/26002/regulating-temperature-of-cider-fermentation

Answer (score 2):

Occasionally - very, very occasionally - this is useful.

But just because the system lets you do it doesn't mean its a good idea. And in fact, the system will warn you if you try it.

[image: Are you sure you want to add another answer?]

> Are you sure you want to add another answer?
>
> You could use the edit link to refine and improve your existing answer, instead.

Comment: Its just strange odd that the system allows it at all, despite warnings.  I think its fine to offer an answer to your own question.  But if you have the power to offer several answers it just shows that you don't know the answer.  A questioner should just sit back and wait for an answer.  It seems to be a big flaw in the set up to me.

Answer (score 1):

Answering your own question once in a "here's a different way that worked well/didn't work at all" sense seems like something one should be able to do.   Multiple times does seem weird, though turning it into a wiki does counter that oddness to some extent.

At some point you have to rely on the users to behave in rational ways, I suppose.